# calling a stored mySql procedure in php + erro

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am wondering  if anyone can tell me where I am going wrong.  I am new to mySql and have little experience with php but am trying to call a stored procedure call AddStudy from a mysql database through php.  Here is the code I have

```
//set up our connection to the database
$con = mysql_connect("umemlists.org","umemlist_umbc1",'U[$X7VHO7XT3');
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$stmt = "call SaveStudy('james', 1234, 'm', 12, 0, 0, 'umbc', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, "", 0, -1)";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $stmt);
```

I am getting an error that says

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

I am wondering if anyone could tell me if I am using the right syntax/method for calling the stored procedure in my database and if so any suggestions as to how I may be able to troubleshoot the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the double quotes inside your query:

```
$stmt = "call SaveStudy('james', 1234, 'm', 12, 0, 0, 'umbc', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, "", 0, -1)";
```

should be

```
$stmt = "call SaveStudy('james', 1234, 'm', 12, 0, 0, 'umbc', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 0, -1)";
```

Comment: Yes it was the double quotes that was causing the problem thanks